# Does it make sense to say that the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ has a surface area of $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, spherical-coordinates

My problem is, if we take the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $m_n$, we can calculate that, for the unit $(n-1)$-sphere, is

$$\sigma(S^n) = \frac{2\pi^{(n+1)/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}.$$

If we want to obtain the limit, we can do:

\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma(S^{n-1}) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \chi_{\{x \ :\  x \in S^{n-1}\}}(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\varphi_{n-1}=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\varphi_{n-2}=0}^{\pi} \cdots \int_{\varphi_1}^\pi \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin(\varphi_k)^{n-k-1} \mathrm{d}\varphi_1 \mathrm{d}\varphi_2 \cdots\mathrm{d}\varphi_{n-1}.\end{align}

So we should be able to use Dominated Convergence since the integrand is bounded by $1$.

In this case the integrand becomes $0$ almost everywhere.

I have not treated infinite-dimensional spaces almost at all so I don't know if this is sound.

Comment: DCT states that if $|f_n| \le g$ **and** $\int g < \infty$, then $\lim \int f_n = \int \lim f_n$. In each case, the integral should be taken over the same space.  In your computation, you are integrating $f_n$ over $\mathbb{R}_n$, hence the space changes at ever step of the process.  It is unclear how this makes sense.

Comment: You'd need to define a measure on (the unit sphere of) $\ell^2$ (what you called $\Bbb{R}_\infty$)